# How to read from an already existing dropdown list and click on OK button using autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

`ControlGet List,List,,DropDownList, Installer Language,English
Control,Choose,1,ComboBox,DropDown`

This is the snippet which I am using to read from the dropdownlist and it is not working. Please tell me what is the right snippet to be use here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying here. This code is something similar to what you require...

```
Gui, Add, DDL, %chooseMonth% vMonthSelected,January||February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December
```

It allows you to select Month from the drop down list and stores the selected value in variable `chooseMonth`